# swithcing to next textview

Tags: android, eclipse, button, textview

Ok im making  app and it have 15 button's and 6 textview's.I want when I press first button to change value of first textview(value is "") to something (number one for example).But problem is when i press second button if first textview is already set to some value to set set second textview to second value.

If you need something else ask in comments (sorry for bad English)

here is what I was doing(this is under onclick)when i press second button

```
if(textview1.equals("1")){
            textview2.setText("2");}
            else if (textview1.equals("")){
            textview1.setText("2");
            }
```

Comment: `textview1.equals("1")` textView1 is apparently not a String. probably a TextView.

Comment: change textview1.equals("1") to textview1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("1")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you wish to show last 6 buttons pressed.
Store all pressed buttons in a `List` (i.e. `LinkedList`) of size 6. Initially, it will be empty.

Then whenever any button is pressed do two things:
1) add it to the `List` and delete old elements if size exceeds six.
2) set button values from `List`.

Second step can be achieved like this:

```
// all TextViews should be in a list
private List<TextView> textViews;

// declare as field
private List<String> memoryQueue = new ArrayList<String>();

public void update() {
    //set fields for the pressed buttons
    for (int i=0; i<6 && i<memoryQueue.size(); i++) {
        String text = memoryQueue.get(i);
        textViews.get(i).setText(text);
    }

    // set empty fields
    for (int i = memoryQueue.size(); i<6; i++) {
        textViews.get(i).setText("");
    }
}
```

This code snippet assumes that you store your `TextView`s in a `List`.

And Easiest way to keep track of last six button:

```
public void buttonPressed(Button button) {
    //get text based on your button
    String text = button.getText();

    if (memoryQueue.contains(text)) {
         return;
    }

    memoryQueue.add(text);
    if (memoryQueue.size() > 6) {
        memoryQueue.remove(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: cant understand this too well but maybe it will help

Comment: It is a List where you store last six button pressed (updated with step 1).

Comment: still cant get it working (not showing memory queue as command)

Comment: Sorry, memoryQueue is a variable. In your constuctir or onCreate method put List<String> memoryQueue = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: Updated code to cover for corner cases when `memoryQueue` is smaller than 6 elements.

Comment: I think it should be 5 as size of memory because you take 0 as slot too.

Comment: In the `for` loops `i` is smaller than 6, therefore i=0,1,2,3,4,5.
In the update method `size()` will return the element count which is six.
Indexing might be a bit confusing.

Comment: If you want to use only distinct values then add a check in your update method. Updated the code.

Comment: can use this as method under onCreate and how(newbie question)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're concerned with the text inside of your text view, you should be using the object's getText method:

```
if( textview1.getText().equals("1") ){ // Edited
    textview2.setText("2");
} else if (textview1.getText().equals("")){ //Edited
    textview1.setText("2");
}
```

Comment: You can't compare two `String` with `==` operator.

Comment: Good catch.  can I get my point back?  I was on the right track.. I just edited

Answer (score 0):

At first, you have to get the `String` text from `TextView` using `getText()` method then you can compare that `String` with another `String`. Now, change your condition as follows...

```
if(textview1.getText().toString().equals("1")){
    textview2.setText("2");}
else if (textview1.getText().toString().equals("")){
    textview1.setText("2");
}
```

Comment: but this is only when i use two buttons